# Git flow with Github deployment

Tags: git, deployment, github, release, git-flow

I am in a team of 4 other developers and we are learning GIT and using the gitflow model and github as the central repo. So far we have created the central repository on github and we can create features, push them to the central repo and pull from there to get each others changes.

All developers work on their local machine, however we have 3 servers setup - development, staging and production.

Development is where everyone can view each others changes and once we are happy we will transfer to staging. This is where testing will take place to ensure everything is ok before we finally make the website live on production.

The website is currently finished and we have cloned the repository on the development server and pulled all the website files so we can see all changes on there. However, we're now unsure we should deploy to staging and finally to production.

1. Do we create a release branch locally first and push to the central repo?
2. Do we clone the central repo on the staging and production server?
3. If so, do we pull from he central repo or shouldn't we ever use GIT on the production server? I've read about using rsync as well as hooks?!

If someone can please explain the next steps or point me to somewhere which explains it that would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have one person who is in charge of deploying to the different servers, especially staging and production.
That way when you create a release branch, this branch would be deployed on the staging server. When the release branch is finished you deploy the master branch to the production server.

You can clone the repo to staging and production, just make sure the .git directory has proper security *(.htaccess is your friend :))*, so that non-developers can't access that directory.

I would use git pull on the production server. I've read about rsync and hooks as well, but just git works just fine for me.

Now sometimes when I work for a client that doesn't don't allow git on the server and I use ftp. There is a Pyhton program on github called [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) which I adapted a little bit to accommodate git-flow. I haven't put that version on github, maybe I should.

***As a follow up to the first comment***
The person who does the staging and production releases would do the following steps on his/her local machine:

```
git flow release start -F 1.0
```

do some work, like update version number
Publish it to github

```
git flow release publish 1.0
```

On the staging server:

```
git pull origin release/1.0
```

After the staging period is over, on the local machine

```
git flow release finish 1.0
```

On the production server

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. So just use GIT the same way on staging and production as I would on my local or development server but pull from master instead of develop? i.e git pull origin master

Comment: Yeah, that's how I would do it, I updated the answer to show the steps. I might have missed a few small steps, but that would be the way to go, IMHO

Comment: Thanks. When you say update version number does git flow do this as part of `git flow release publish 1.0`? Whats the difference between publishing the release whilst its still open locally and finishing the release locally and pushing to github?

Comment: git flow doesn't update version numbers in your software, you need to do that manually or use [git-flow (AVH Edition)](http://bit.ly/S2k1S2) which supports the use of hooks and filters. Publishing you just push the release branch to origin. Finishing a release means it merges into the master branch and into the develop branch.

Comment: OK thanks. So you would publish the feature from local, pull it on staging, carry out testing and when happy, finish the feature locally and pull from production? Am I right in thinking I'd never do any actual coding on development, staging or production, these are simply to view (development), test (staging) and show live site (production)? Thanks again.

Comment: I would never do the coding on the servers, always do it locally. I know this is a bit of a pain for small bugs. When you run into a bug, assign a developer to fix it, they can pull the release branch, fix the bug, push the release branch back and you would pull it into the server. The thing that could happen, is that you forget to push the bugfixes back to the shared repository and then with the next release the bug will show its ugly face again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19649/discussion-between-derek-carlisle-and-peter-van-der-does)